# Добавить ячейки в таблицу через JS

Tags: javascript, таблицы

Подскажите ответ. Я хочу, чтоб при нажатии на кнопку срабатывала функция, которая создает таблицу. Код срабатывает, ячейки добавляются, но выдает ошибку. посмотрите пожалуйста, если что, дайте совет, как правильно.

```
<div class="game">
    <input class="btn" type="button" value="Начать" onclick="start()">
    </div>

    <style>
    .game {
        width:500px;
        height:500px;
        background:red;
        text-align:center;
        margin-left:auto;
        margin-right:auto;
        padding:15px;
        box-sizing:border-box;
        background:#FFE4B5;
    }

    .btn {
        width:auto;
        height:30px;
    }


    .table {

        width:450px;
        height:auto;
        margin-left:auto;
        margin-right:auto;
        margin-top:30px;
        margin-bottom:30px;
    }

    .tr {
        width:100%;
        height:70px;
        border:1px solid  blue;
    }

    .td {
        height:auto;
        width:auto;
        border:1px solid green;
    }
    </style>

    <script>
    var bodyGame=document.querySelector('.game');

    function start() {
        var crtTable=document.createElement('table');
        crtTable.classList.add('table');
        bodyGame.appendChild(crtTable);


        for(i=0; i<=4; i++){
            var crtTr=document.createElement('tr');
            crtTr.classList.add('tr');
            crtTable.appendChild(crtTr);
        }

        var t=document.getElementsByTagName('tr');


        for(i=0; i<=t.length; i++){
            for(k=0; k<=4; k++){
                var crtTd=document.createElement('td');
                crtTd.innerHTML='1';
                crtTd.classList.add('td');
                t[i].appendChild(crtTd);
            }
        }

    }
    </script>
```

Comment: `i<=t.length;` -> `i<t.length;`

Comment: Благодарю, ответ исчерпывающий)